# How to read soap response xml in php

Tags: php, soap

This is my Soap Response xml,I need to get `RebillCustomerID`
How I can do this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope                          
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Header><eWAYHeader 
   xmlns="http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill">
    <eWAYCustomerID>87654321</eWAYCustomerID><Username>test@eway.com.au</Username>
      <Password>test123</Password></eWAYHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body>
        <CreateRebillCustomerResponse xmlns="http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill"><CreateRebillCustomerResult>
           <Result>Success</Result><ErrorSeverity /><ErrorDetails />
      <RebillCustomerID>90246</RebillCustomerID></CreateRebillCustomerResult>                             
          </CreateRebillCustomerResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope><pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try the code below. I am assuming your xml response is in `$soapXMLResult` variable

```
$soap     = simplexml_load_string($soapXMLResult);
$response = $soap->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children()->CreateRebillCustomerResponse;
$customerId = (string) $response->CreateRebillCustomerResult->RebillCustomerID;
echo $customerId;
```

Comment: Can you please investigate? I'm unable to get `$customerId;`

Answer (score 1):

How I did, create eway soap request and get eway soap result,may help others!

```
 <?php
    $URL = "https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/test/manageRebill_test.asmx?wsdl";
                $option = array("trace"=>true);
                $client = new SOAPClient($URL, $option);
                $functions = $client->__getFunctions();
        $headeroptions=array('eWAYCustomerID'=>"87654321",'Username'=>"test@eway.com.au","Password"=>"test123");
                $header = new SOAPHeader('http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill', 'eWAYHeader',$headeroptions);

                $bodyoptions = array(
                                "CreateRebillCustomer" => array(
                                    "customerTitle" => "Mr",                   
                                      "customerFirstName"=>"Muhammad",
                                      "customerLastName"=>"Shahzad",
                                      "customerAddress"=>"cust ome rAddress",
                                      "customerSuburb"=>"customer Suburb",
                                      "customerState"=>"ACT",
                                      "customerCompany"=>"customer Company",
                                      "customerPostCode"=>"2345",
                                      "customerCountry"=>">Australia",
                                      "customerEmail"=>"test@gamil.com",
                                      "customerFax"=>"0298989898",
                                      "customerPhone1"=>"0297979797",
                                      "customerPhone2"=>"0297979797",
                                      "customerRef"=>"Ref123",
                                      "customerJobDesc"=>"customerJobDesc",
                                      "customerComments"=>"customerComments",                    
                                      "customerURL" => "http://www.acme.com.au"
                                   )
                                );

                    try{
                        $response = $client->__soapCall("CreateRebillCustomer", $bodyoptions,NULL,$header,$outputHeader);
                        //echo $client->__getLastRequest();
                        //$response = $client->CreateRebillCustomer($bodyoptions);
                        //echo "<pre>";echo "<br/>";
                       // print_r($response);        
                            echo    $result         = $response->CreateRebillCustomerResult->Result;echo "<br/>";
                            echo    $customerId     = $response->CreateRebillCustomerResult->RebillCustomerID;echo "<br/>";
                            echo "<br/>";
                        if($result=='Success' AND $customerId){
                            echo 'Member Created at eWay Successfully!...<br/>';
                            echo 'Creating Recurring Billing Cycle on eWay,Please wait......<br/>';
                            //$UpdateRebillCustomer = CreateRebillEvent($customerId);
                            //print_r($UpdateRebillCustomer);

                        }
                        else{
                            echo    $ErrorSeverity  = $response->CreateRebillCustomerResult->ErrorSeverity;echo "<br/>";
                            echo    $ErrorDetails   = $response->CreateRebillCustomerResult->ErrorDetails;echo "<br/>";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SOAPFault $e){
                        print $e;
                    }

                    if($customerId){


                                $bodyoptions2 = array(
                                "CreateRebillEvent " => array(
                                      "RebillCustomerID" => $customerId,                   
                                      "RebillInvRef" => "Ref123",
                                      "RebillInvDes"=>"description",
                                      "RebillCCName"=>"Mr Andy Person",
                                      "RebillCCNumber"=>"4444333322221111",
                                      "RebillCCExpMonth"=>"12",
                                      "RebillCCExpYear"=>"15",
                                      "RebillInitAmt"=>"100",
                                      "RebillInitDate"=>date('d/m/Y'),
                                      "RebillRecurAmt"=>"200",
                                      "RebillStartDate"=>date('d/m/Y'),
                                      "RebillInterval"=>"31",
                                      "RebillIntervalType"=>"1",
                                      "RebillEndDate"=>"31/12/2013",                     
                                   )
                                );
                        try{    
                            $response = $client->__soapCall("CreateRebillEvent", $bodyoptions2,NULL,$header,$outputHeader);
                            //echo   $client->__getLastRequest();           
                            //print_r($response);
                            echo "<br/>";
                              echo  $result2        = $response->CreateRebillEventResult->Result;echo "<br/>";
                              echo  $RebillCustomerID   = $response->CreateRebillEventResult->RebillCustomerID;echo "<br/>";
                            if($result2=='Success'){
                                echo 'Recurring Cycle Created Successfully at eWay!...<br/>';
                                echo 'Member Id is ===>'.$RebillCustomerID;
                                //$UpdateRebillCustomer = CreateRebillEvent($customerId);
                                //print_r($UpdateRebillCustomer);                           
                            }
                            else{
                                echo    $ErrorSeverity  = $response->CreateRebillEventResult->ErrorSeverity;echo "<br/>";
                                echo    $ErrorDetails   = $response->CreateRebillEventResult->ErrorDetails;echo "<br/>";
                            }

                        }
                     catch(SOAPFault $e){
                        print $e;
                     }

                     }

                  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a client for a SOAP service and you want to manipulate or test their response by placing it in a local file and parsing that (maybe their response has errors and you want to fix the errors yourself), you can override the URL that your soapClient uses to call methods by calling `__soapCall()` directly:

```
$result = $this->soap_client->__soapCall( 'function_call_name', ['location' => $file_location] );
```

Where `$file_location` is the absolute or relative path to your copy of their xml response. What you put as your function call name doesn't matter, since the soap client will get the same xml response regardless of what function you try to call this way. The only thing that matters is that your `$file_location` be correct and that the xml file has the correct permissions to be read by apache if you run this in a browser.

You can then `var_dump($response)` and find the node you need rather than using `simplexml_load_string`. If you do it this way you can easily swap out your xml for their response later on.