# Get Value from given XML using simple load string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi I want to get value from given XML using simple_xml_string but its not working. XML is given below:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
        <eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From>
        <eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">info@gandakiintl.com</eb:PartyId></eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>T198</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>111@gandakiintl.com</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service eb:type="SabreXML">Enhanced Air Book Request</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1522435489615361760</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-01-11T13:36:01</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:11110info@gandakiintl.com</eb:RefToMessageId>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
            Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3319706757025363837!367706!0
        </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
    <soap-env:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidSecurityToken</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Invalid or Expired binary security token: Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3319706757025363837!367706!0</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <StackTrace>
                com.sabre.universalservices.base.session.SessionException: errors.session.USG_INVALID_SECURITY_TOKEN
            </StackTrace>
        </detail>
    </soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

From above xml I want to get faultCode node value But I am not able to get. Please help. I tried doing it but its not working.

```
 $feed = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $a = $feed->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
 var_dump($a->Fault->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'));
```

Edited:
Output I get is: Node no longer exists. But I want to get "soap-env:Client.InvalidSecurityToken" value.

Comment: Please expand on **not working**.  What about it isn't working? Do you get an error? Do you get a value, but not the value you expect?  Be specific.  *A problem well defined is half solved already*.

Comment: Hi I had edited the question. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read soap response xml in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393140/how-to-read-soap-response-xml-in-php)

Comment: I already tried it. But its error.

Comment: Can't help if you don't want to share the error.  And show exactly what you've tried.  Be specific.  Programming is *Very, very* detail oriented, and the specifics matter!