# How to get SOAP response from with PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am working on a SOAP web service

And I made call into the web service to get all the methods with the code below

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/eSalesTest/webservice/xxx.asmx?wsdl");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//var_dump($client->__getTypes());


which gave me something like

 1 => string 'Save3rdPartyPolicyResponse Save3rdPartyPolicy(Save3rdPartyPolicy $parameters)' (length=77)
  2 => string 'SaveTravelPolicyResponse SaveTravelPolicy(SaveTravelPolicy $parameters)' (length=71)
  3 => string 'Book3rdPartyMotorResponse Book3rdPartyMotor(Book3rdPartyMotor $parameters)' (length=74)
  4 => string 'BookComprehensiveMotorResponse BookComprehensiveMotor(BookComprehensiveMotor $parameters)' (length=89)
  5 => string 'BookTravelPolicyResponse BookTravelPolicy(BookTravelPolicy $parameters)' (length=71)
  6 => string 'GetVehicleMakesResponse GetVehicleMakes(GetVehicleMakes $parameters)' (length=68)
  7 => string 'GetThirdPartyCategoriesResponse GetThirdPartyCategories(GetThirdPartyCategories $parameters)' (length=92)
  8 => string 'GetThridPartyPremiumResponse GetThridPartyPremium(GetThridPartyPremium $parameters)' (length=83)
  9 => string 'SaveComprehensiveMotorResponse SaveComprehensiveMotor(SaveComprehensiveMotor $parameters)' (length=89)
  10 => string 'BookMIPResponse BookMIP(BookMIP $parameters)' (length=44)
  11 => string 'SaveMIPResponse SaveMIP(SaveMIP $parameters)' (length=44)
```

However, what I want is to be able to get response request and populate it on my form.

I already did that using soapUI and got the response in xml format like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetStatesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetStatesResult>[{"Code":"6","Text":"Abia"},{"Code":"7","Text":"Adamawa"},{"Code":"8","Text":"Akwa Ibom"},{"Code":"9","Text":"Anambra"},{"Code":"10","Text":"Bauchi"},{"Code":"11","Text":"Bayelsa"},{"Code":"12","Text":"Benue"},{"Code":"13","Text":"Bornu"},{"Code":"14","Text":"Cross River "},{"Code":"15","Text":"Delta"},{"Code":"16","Text":"Ebonyi "},{"Code":"17","Text":"Edo"},{"Code":"18","Text":"Ekiti"},{"Code":"19","Text":"Enugu"},{"Code":"5","Text":"Federal Capital Territory"},{"Code":"42","Text":"Foreign Offices"},{"Code":"20","Text":"Gombe"},{"Code":"21","Text":"Imo"},{"Code":"22","Text":"Jigawa"},{"Code":"23","Text":"Kaduna"},{"Code":"24","Text":"Kano"},{"Code":"25","Text":"Katsina"},{"Code":"26","Text":"Kebbi"},{"Code":"27","Text":"Kogi"},{"Code":"28","Text":"Kwara"},{"Code":"29","Text":"Lagos"},{"Code":"30","Text":"Nasarawa"},{"Code":"31","Text":"Niger"},{"Code":"32","Text":"Ogun"},{"Code":"33","Text":"Ondo"},{"Code":"34","Text":"Osun"},{"Code":"35","Text":"Oyo"},{"Code":"36","Text":"Plateau"},{"Code":"37","Text":"Rivers"},{"Code":"38","Text":"Sokoto"},{"Code":"39","Text":"Taraba"},{"Code":"40","Text":"Yobe"},{"Code":"41","Text":"Zamfara"}]</GetStatesResult>
      </GetStatesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Kindly explain better what I'm doing or the next step to do as to do

Comment: is this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393140/how-to-read-soap-response-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0):

At first try this example:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL');

$parameters = array(
    'IPAddress' => '8.8.8.8',
);
$result = $client->GetGeoIP($parameters);

print_r($result);
```

Then try this:

```
// Change the url
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.xxxxxxx.com/eSalesTest/webservice/xxx.asmx?wsdl');

$parameters = array(
    'token' => 'my-secret-token'
);
$result = $client->GetStates($parameters);

// Decode the json string
$json = $result->GetStatesResult;
$items = json_decode($json, true);

// Output
echo '<select name="states">';
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $code = htmlspecialchars($item['Code'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
    $text = htmlspecialchars($item['Text'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
    echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $code, $text);
}
echo '</select> ';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried using the method above, $client = new SoapClient("https://www.xxxx.com/eSalesTest/webservice/xxx.asmx?wsdl");
$param = ['my generated token'];
$result = $client->GetStates($param);
// Decode the json string
$data = json_decode($result->GetStates);
print_r($data);     but getting  Undefined property: stdClass::$GetStates in

Comment: Also, printing $result only gave       stdClass Object ( [GetStatesResult] => )     only with no error

Comment: I think it must be a named parameter like: $parameters = array(
    'token' => 'my-secret-token',
);
Without more details about the SOAP API it's impossible to see whats wrong.

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works perfectly now. I have something like this on my browser, stdClass Object ( [GetStatesResult] => [{"Code":"6","Text":"Abia"},{"Code":"7","Text":"Adamawa"},{"Code":"8","Text":"Akwa Ibom"},{"Code":"9","Text":"Anambra"},{"Code":"41","Text":"Zamfara"}] ).      Please how do i populate it in select field. Thanks alot for your assistance

Comment: I just added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works . Please one more thing, i generate the token used for authentication parameters from soapUI with given username and password, however the token expires after 10min and return blank data. is there any solution to staying authenticated?

Comment: 1 option: You could request a new token for every request
2 option: Get a token and store it together with a self calculated expire date (expire = now + 9min). If the date token is valid take it again, if the token is invalid get a new token and store it.

Comment: Thanks, iv been trying to work on generating the token with the username and password usinng the code below.     $resulttoken = $client->getToken($param2);  where $param2 is an array of username and password. Im i doing the right thing

Comment: Please give me an insight on how to generate token with username given username and password. Thanks

Comment: This depends on the Webservice. You should look into the documentation of this specific SOAP Webservice.